# MKReverseGeocoder updating text field

Tags: ios, ios4, mkmapview

I have the same solution like in Uber app. I want to locate myself (this is simple) and put some pin on the center of screen. When I scroll map, red pin stays in center of screen, and in text field is updated street name where is red pin.

I found that I must to use overlay map for this centered pin, but I don't know what to do with reverse geocoding and text field.

There is some example of this behavior or can you give some sample, or anything how to make this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) get the center coordinate

`CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = mapview.centerCoordinate`;

2) reverse geocode the coordinate

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
[geocoder setDelegate:self];
[geocoder start];
```

3) this callback delegate will give you what you want. Check placemark

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
```